# Office VBA controls transparacy not working since October 2016 office update

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

It appears that the latest Office update (Version 1609 (Build 7369.2024))
released in September or October has made it impossible (without using windows APIs) to switch some control backstyles to transparent (i.e. labels/ checkboxes/ option buttons etc.)

I have managed to find one other post on MSDN relating to this issue which can be found at the following link (but without resolution):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/608e9a9b-69a2-44b3-8ab4-10fe2fe1c04e/no-more-transparent-labels-on-vba-userforms?forum=officegeneral

This problem relates to Excel and Word as a minimum as that is all I have tested but would guess the same goes for all office VBA applications.

Now - as you might imagine, this has put me in a bit of a pickle as I use transparent labels etc. throughout my applications and as a result, forms now look at best awful and at worst simply do not work.

Has anyone got a fix or any further information on this?

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: *at best awful and at worst simply do not work* - are you overlapping form controls? If so, that isn't best-practice. If not, then a work-around could be to set the backcolor to the same value as the form. That said, that's some scary glitch indeed!

Comment: Scary indeed - this was fist notified to me by one of my customers, who happens to be Microsoft which is kind of ironic.

Answer (score 0):

Office introduced a major bug in October that influences VBA behavior. The following link explains the situation in more detail.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9796fd67-e65c-4086-a2db-b990a17077b8/office-vba-controls-transparacy-not-working-since-october-2016-office-update?forum=Office2016ITPro

Comment: When giving a link as an answer, try to extract the important information from it so people can see directly what you are referring to. :)

Comment: This error is so far reaching I thought the link was the best way to go. Here is one of the main responses which suggest that MS might fix it.

Comment: Posted Friday, October, 2016 10:12 PM
Hi everyone,

The team has checked in a fix for the BackStyle/transparency issue. They've also fixed (or are in the progress of fixing) several other forms-related issues that occurred after recent Office updates. When these fixes get released, I'll come back to this thread and let you know.

Anneliese